# Proof of the halting problem being undecidable

Tags: undecidability

To prove the that the halting problem is undecidable I was provided with 5 lemmas.
I understood each Lemma individually and also the proof itself. What I'm confused about is that one of the Lemmas seem like it didnt contribute to the proof at all. If someone could tell me if I have missed the importance of the Lemma then I would be very grateful.

Lemma 1: If a language is decidable it is acceptable.

Lemma 2: If a language is decidable so is its complement.

Lemma 3: If a language and its complement is acceptable then the language is decidable.

Lemma 4: The halting language is acceptable (the universal turing machine accepts it)

Lemma 5: The diagonal language is not acceptable.

The proof goes, if the halting problem is decidable, then M_h must exist. We can use M_h to make a turing machine that decides the complement of the diagonal language. Well, lemma 2 signifies that the diagonal language must then be decidable. Now lemma 1 makes the diagonal language acceptable. This contradicts lemma 5. The existence of M_h led to a contradiction so M_h does not exist.

Where does Lemma 3 play into this. Lemma 4 at least allows us to explain a turing machine can simulate other turing machines, but Lemma 3 seemingly does nothing?